# Add permissions for user on Slack

Tags: slack, slack-api

How can we add more scopes/permissions for a user when he signs into slack using Sign in to Slack button. I have added the scopes in the Outh permissions/scopes on my Slack App.it works for the primary owner but not for other users.
I have a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51332569/only-primary-owner-can-post-message-on-slack?noredirect=1#comment89673986_51332569). I think I figured out the that I have to add permissions but cannot figure out how. I tried adding it to the initial oauth flow of the sign in with Slack button but it says that I am not allowed to use other scopes with identity.basic.

```
  <div class="form-group">
                <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                    <a href="https://slack.com/oauth/authorize?scope=identity.basic,identity.email,identity.team,identity.avatar&client_id=373568302675.374024189699">
                        <img alt="Sign in with Slack" height="40" width="172" src="https://platform.slack-edge.com/img/sign_in_with_slack.png"
                             srcset="https://platform.slack-edge.com/img/sign_in_with_slack.png 1x, https://platform.slack-edge.com/img/sign_in_with_slack@2x.png 2x" />
                    </a>
                </div>
            </div>
```

Can someone tell me exactly where should I add the permissions for users who are not primary owners?

I made another button on the cshtml as follows:

```
<input type="button" value="Authenticate again to send Message" class="btn btn-warning" onclick="location.href = 'https://slack.com/oauth/authorize?scope=incoming-webhook,im:write,chat:write:user&client_id=373568302675.374024189699'"/>
```

And then on click it is leading to the same function as Sign in with Slack which is as follows:

```
public SlackAuthToken GetAccessToken(ProgramParameter startParam, string clientId, string clientSecret, string code)
        {
            using (var client = new WebClient())
            {
                string apiUrl = GetApiUrl(startParam);
                string url = apiUrl + "/oauth.access?client_id=" + clientId + "&client_secret=" + clientSecret + "&code=" + code;
                var response = client.DownloadString(url);

                SlackAuthToken slackTest = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<SlackAuthToken>(response);
                string accessToken = slackTest.AccessToken;
                string urlUserIdentity = "https://slack.com/api/users.identity?token=" + accessToken;
                var responseUser = client.DownloadString(urlUserIdentity);
                SlackAuthToken slack = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<SlackAuthToken>(responseUser);
                return slackTest;
            }

        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to change the scope parameter in the URL. You can't use `identity.*` scope in combinations with other ones, try `identify` instead.

`identity.*` are meant for auth only, not to install apps/bots/commands.

Comment: How do I add two scopes in the same auth flow? Check my comment on the [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51332569/only-primary-owner-can-post-message-on-slack?noredirect=1#comment89707137_51332569) question. I am new to coding and Slack api and would really appreciate if you could help me here.

Answer (score 0):

The "Sign-in with Slack" feature is not meant to give users permissions on Slack, but to authenticate existing Slack users on a 3rd party website.

If you want to access Slack API methods from your website, you need to do that through a Slack app that is installed once by an admin and will give you an access token with permissions as defined and requested by the the Slack app. But that is usually not meant to work on-behalf of a user, but as it own entity, namely a Slack app.

See also [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50957716/4379151) to better understand the difference between "Sign-in with Slack" and "Add to Slack".

If you really want your website to be able to act (e.g. post Slack messages) on behalf of multiple users than this is what you need to do:

1. Each of your users need to install your Slack app once using "Add to Slack" Oauth process and with all needed permissions. This is called "configurations" in Slack.
2. You app needs to collect and store the access token received from each installation
3. Then your website can use "Sign-in with Slack" to identify a user and assuming a "configuration" has been created use the matching access token (from #2) for each subsequent API call for that user (e.g. to send a message on his behalf)

Comment: I got a response from Slack as follows: SIWS(Sign in with Slack) scopes cannot be combined with non-SIWS scopes in the same Oauth flow so users will need to be put through the Oauth flow for apps that have SIWS scopes twice: 1. First, with just the identity.* scopes and 2.Next, with nay of the non-SIWS scopes. But, I am failing to understand how to have two scopes. Do I add another api call for chat:write or add it somehow in the cshtml code for the button. So, is it possible to not add the Slack button and still do the above?

Comment: no. each user needs to first install your Slack app with "Add to Slack" once. That is how your website gets a token with permissions for user. After that the users can use SIWS to sign-in to your website. And you website can use previously stored token to issue API methods on behalf of the user

Comment: I added a regular button and have it redirecting to the following url:     <input type="button" value="Authenticate again to send Message" class="btn btn-warning" onclick="location.href = 'https://slack.com/oauth/authorize?scope=im:write,chat:write:user&client_id=373568302675.374024189699';"/> and took it through the Oauth step again and I was able to get all users to send the message to others. I did not use the Add to Slack button. However, the functionality remained the same. Should I post an answer for this then? Thank you for your input, it helped me ask a better question from Slack Team.

Comment: that will work, but now you are re-installing your Slack app every time someone clicks the button. are you sure that is what you want? with the approach I outlined above you have to install it only once. But if that is the approach you want: yes, please put it as answer

Comment: I did save the access token of the user who clicks on the button. Would that too cause re-installing everytime someone clicks on it? I am sorry, I want to understand how the regular button is different from Add to Slack button. I am updating the question above to show my codes. I do not want to keep re-installing the app again and again.